# mysql simple where clause not working?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Database changed

mysql> select * from userinfo;
+-----------+----------+-----------------------+------------+
| firstname | lastname | username              | password   |
+-----------+----------+-----------------------+------------+
|  asif     |  kolu    |  ashufound            |  123456    |
|  faisal   |  samad   |  tfhgfhgfh@gmail.com  |  123456    |
|  kamran   |  shafat  |  kamthemaam           |  kamoos    |
|  ubaid    |  mir     |  sadfsfsff@yahoo.com  |  qwertasd  |
|  majid    |  mir     |  zsffsa               |  afdfdsf   |
+-----------+----------+-----------------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT  * from userinfo WHERE lastname = 'mir';
Empty set (0.10 sec)

mysql> SELECT  * from userinfo WHERE lastname='mir';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

what is wrong with this code simple where clause not working?actually problem is in the code for insert i think

Comment: Are you sure lastname doesn't have a trailing space?

Comment: Can you try with `SELECT  * from userinfo WHERE last name LIKE '%mir%'`?

Comment: @echo_Me : Have I said anything about solution? It is just a way to understand if there are extra spaces. He can also use `TRIM` to check it, if you want something more accurate.

Comment: yaa was able to that and thanx  but actually i enter data from struts form and now i have no idea whats happening

Comment: I'm glad you're not storing passwords in plain-text

Comment: thank u guys found the error.... ;) stackoverflow rocks

Comment: It's good to share the solution as well if the problem is solved to help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

your last name in your table may have a space before or after `mir`

```
   mir
  ^---^---look and remove spaces from here in your table
```

Answer (score 1):

I m usign select Query in this the where clause doesnt working query is

```
select * from table_t where id = '96'
```

this query is resulting 0 rows but

when  i try

```
select * from table_t where id like '96'
```

this query is working fine.

and when i try like with column name like

```
select id from table_t where id like '96'
```

returning 0 rows

the id is auto generated primary key not have white spaces

why????
is there any database issue???
this query is working fine on my local machine but when i try it online it is misbehaving.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

1- You may have space before or after "mir".

2- You may have special (invisible) characters before or after 'mir' or even between its characters.

To solve this problem, I suggest to do this first:

```
Update userinfo
    set lastname = 'mir' 
    where (username = 'sadfsfsff@yahoo.com') or (username = 'zsffsa')
```

And then, run this to check:

```
Select * from userinfo where lastname = 'mir'
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some good answers but in the case that you couldn't update leading or trailing spaces in your entire db for each name, you could write the select a little differently. If it is a space issue, try this.

```
SELECT  * from userinfo WHERE TRIM(lastname) = TRIM('mir')
```

If that doesn't work, try `LIKE` and see if you get results. That could help with debugging.

```
SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE lastname LIKE '%mir%'
```